# Calling href from dropdown in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following drop down using angularjs.

```
   <select ng-href="#/edit/{{name.id}}" class="form-control"  id="{{name.id}}">  
   <option ng-repeat="name in addas | filter:cc"
   id="{{name.id}}" value="{{name.name}}">{{name.as_number}}</option>
  </select>
```

I am trying to call href on selected option in the drop down. The drop down populates fine. When I select any option it doesn't do anything or call the url. 
Please let me know how I can achieve this in angularjs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<select ng-model="adda" ng-options="a.name for a in addas" ng-change="onChange()">  
</select>
```

Sample controller:

```
function Ctrl($scope, $location) {
    $scope.addas = [
        {id: 1, name: 'a1', as_number: 1},
        {id: 2, name: 'a2', as_number: 2},
        {id: 3, name: 'a3', as_number: 3}
    ];

    $scope.onChange = function() {
        $location.path('/edit/' + $scope.adda.id);
    }
}
```

`$location.path()` does not seem to have any effect int the fiddle so instead the path is just displayed on the page but it should work as expected otherwise.

---

There is a number of things wrong with your approach. First of all you use `ng-repeat` on the option element so `name.id` won't be available outside of that element. It would probably be `undefined` when you use it in `ng-href` (unless you have it defined in the `$parent` scope as well but if I understand correctly this is not true).

Comment: I can't get this to work. See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GruffBunny/C3Adv/15/)

Comment: Can you be more specific? I see a lot of paragraphs added to the html but no other changes. $location.path() has no effect inside the fiddle - thats for sure. I would guess it must be due to some restrictions imposed by fiddle itself. If I take the code from your updated fiddle and paste it in a new controller in a fresh project (generated with yeoman) then it works. The path is being changed to whatever I select. The path needs to be valid so I also configured a new route /edit/:id in app.js.

Comment: On selecting a1 in the dropdown it doesn't scroll to the paragraph with id 1. Don't think it's a problem with the fiddle, all I did was include extra paragraphs to show that it doesn't scroll to the required location. NB the question url is to a fragment (#/edit/...).

Comment: It was my understanding the question was how to manipulate the path in a simple way in general. If you would only want to change the hash fragment then you would indeed use $location.hash instead of $location.path. I'am afraid that in that case, again, if I create a simple demo it works locally but does not work in the fiddle. The internal state is being changed - getting the path or hash afterwards return the new values. It could be considered a serious bug in angular... but it works locally! Thus, fiddle issue.

Answer (score 2):

The select statement looks a bit over complex to me and contains a few errors. Try this simpler version:

```
<select ng-model='adda'
        ng-options='as_number for name in addas' 
        ng-change='scrollToName()'>  
</select>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.scrollToName = function(){
    $location.hash($scope.adda.id);
    $anchorScroll()
};
```

Don't forget to inject `$location` and `$anchorScroll` into the controller.